# How can I log an audit trail to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to write a logging model and controller, to log everything that user does. I was thinking about creating a db table with from ip address, controller that user called, view that was displayed and params.inspect.

Is there a way to get to a variable which controller is currently being used? What is the best way to deploy this? Is out there a gem that do all this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the log level in production to :debug then every request is logged with the information you need. Perhaps, it might be easier to write a parser for the debug production log.

If you prefer, you can also add a filter to your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :log_activity

  def log_activity
    if Rails.env == 'production'
      @logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/activity.log")
      values = [
        request.remote_ip,
        controller_name,
        action_name,
        params.inspect
      ]
      @logger.info "#{values.join ' | '}"
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

this might not be complete as you want the output to be more verbose, but this is the idea.

Comment: Doesn't `params` already contain controller name and action name? Looks like redundancy. And BTW, are you sure about `controller.name`. I believe it has to be `controller_name`.

Comment: Indeed, the information is already included within the params hash, however it is not very easy to parse from there with (let's say) grep. The relevant section from the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters

Comment: I thought that as far as a log record already has controler/action names, you can exclude them from params: `params.except(:controller, :action).inspect`.

Comment: Thank you, in this I got everything I need, but I will implement it with database, so that user admin can see what users did through web interface, and I can filter it...

Comment: It is more model-centered, but perhaps you might also be able to use https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail, which gives you versioning for every model you want.